# Accumulo on Cloudera CDH4 - Access denied when starting components

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, accumulo

I have a small cluster up and running with Cloudera CDH4 Hadoop and Map Reduce v1.  Namenode/Secondary Namenode/Jobtracker all on different machines.  My three servers are also acting as Zookeeper servers.

I'm trying to install Accumulo 1.4.4 on top of this cluster.  I get the same behavior with Accumulo 1.5.0.  I am able to `bin/accumulo init` and initialize Accumulo, but starting the individual components fail.  I'm trying to make my Namenode the Accumulo master.

`bin/start-server.sh localhost monitor` spits out a very encouraging `Starting monitor on localhost`, but nothing gets started.  If I examine logs/monitor_localhost.err I find a stacktrace:

```
-bash-4.1$ cat logs/monitor_localhost.err
Thread "monitor" died null
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
    at org.apache.accumulo.start.Main$1.run(Main.java:91)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache$Key.<init>(FileSystem.java:2464)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache$Key.<init>(FileSystem.java:2456)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2323)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:351)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:163)
    at org.apache.accumulo.core.file.FileUtil.getFileSystem(FileUtil.java:554)
    at org.apache.accumulo.core.client.ZooKeeperInstance.getInstanceIDFromHdfs(ZooKeeperInstance.java:258)
    at org.apache.accumulo.server.conf.ZooConfiguration.getInstance(ZooConfiguration.java:65)
    at org.apache.accumulo.server.conf.ServerConfiguration.getZooConfiguration(ServerConfiguration.java:49)
    at org.apache.accumulo.server.conf.ServerConfiguration.getSystemConfiguration(ServerConfiguration.java:58)
    at org.apache.accumulo.server.monitor.Monitor.run(Monitor.java:440)
    at org.apache.accumulo.server.monitor.Monitor.main(Monitor.java:433)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission accessDeclaredMembers)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:399)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:557)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
    at java.lang.Class.checkMemberAccess(Class.java:2237)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1805)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredFieldsIncludingInherited(ReflectionUtils.java:315)
    at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MetricsSourceBuilder.initRegistry(MetricsSourceBuilder.java:92)
    at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MetricsSourceBuilder.<init>(MetricsSourceBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MetricsAnnotations.newSourceBuilder(MetricsAnnotations.java:42)
    at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl.register(MetricsSystemImpl.java:212)
    at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.MetricsSystem.register(MetricsSystem.java:54)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation$UgiMetrics.create(UserGroupInformation.java:97)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.<clinit>(UserGroupInformation.java:190)
    ... 18 more
```

The AccessControlException: access denied looks like the important line to me, but I can't imagine what access is being restricted.  I'm running everything as the hdfs user, which owns the entire /opt/accumulo-1.4.4/ directory where accumulo is un-tarred.  The /accumulo directory in HDFS is also owned by the hdfs user.  SELinux is permissive.  Searching online has proved fruitless, has anyone dealt with this error before?

Much thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started browsing the Apache accumulo-users mailing list archive and came across the solution.

http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/accumulo-user/201312.mbox/%3CB9CB2B2BF27F0F46B8ECF781831E00E710970A9F%400015-its-exmb10.us.saic.com%3E

I was copying the accumulo.policy.example to accumulo.policy because I thought I needed it in my configuration.  Once I deleted the accumulo.policy file my issues went away and I've been able to stand up Accumulo (1.5.0 at least, 1.4.4 still has some issues for me)